# Is this approach of returning exceptions is correct?

Tags: symfony

Is my approach of return Exceptions and user object from the registration service to the controller and returning the result as json correct ? I am making RESTful API and I am not sure if I am on the right way. My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Service\RegistrationService;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

class RegistrationController
{
    public function __construct(
        private RegistrationService $registrationService,
    )
    {
    }

    #[Route(path: '/api/v1/register', methods: 'POST')]
    public function register(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $registeredUser = $this->registrationService->register($request->request->all());
        if ($registeredUser instanceof \Exception) {
            return new JsonResponse([
                'type' => 'error',
                'content' => $registeredUser->getMessage(),
                'status' => $registeredUser->getCode()
            ]);
        }

        // Here will serialize the $registeredUser object
        // and will return it as content in the JsonResponse
        
        return new JsonResponse([
            'type' => 'success',
            'content' => $serializedUser,
            'status' => 200
        ]);
    }
}
```

And my registration service:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Service;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

final class RegistrationService
{
    public function __construct(
        private UserRepository $userRepository,
        private ValidatorInterface $validator
    )
    {
    }

    public function register(array $userData): User|\Exception
    {
        if (!$this->checkIfUserExists($userData['email'])) {
            $user = new User(
                $userData['email'],
                $userData['password'],
                $userData['referralCode']
            );
            $errors = $this->validator->validate($user);
            if (count($errors) > 0) {
                return new \Exception(message: (string)$errors, code: 400);
            }

            $this->userRepository->add($user, true);

            return $user;
        }

        return new \Exception(message: 'User with this email already exists!', code: 409);
    }

    private function checkIfUserExists(string $email): bool
    {
        return $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $email]) !== null;
    }
}
```

**Will be thankful or any advises!**

Answer (score 0):

Yes that works. The best one I have seen is to have a middleware which has mapping between more specific error messages and less specific error messages. Before returning the exception to the user the middleware logs it and sends less specific errror messages to end user. Depending on your api, you may not want end user to see specific error messages but still might want to log them